# problem in the Logistic Regression for solver

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using the Logistic Regression for modeling. But while trying the multiple solvers when i applied the solver = "multinomial" i got this

---

```
import sklearn as skl

skl.__version__
'0.21.2'

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(multiclass_logistic_data, labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)

cv_reg = linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(solver='multinomial', max_iter=1000)
cv_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-6d16d00d0653> in <module>
----> 1 cv_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

E:\Anaconda_Install\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1970         self : object
   1971         """
-> 1972         solver = _check_solver(self.solver, self.penalty, self.dual)
   1973 
   1974         if not isinstance(self.max_iter, numbers.Number) or self.max_iter < 0:

E:\Anaconda_Install\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in _check_solver(solver, penalty, dual)
    435     if solver not in all_solvers:
    436         raise ValueError("Logistic Regression supports only solvers in %s, got"
--> 437                          " %s." % (all_solvers, solver))
    438 
    439     all_penalties = ['l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet', 'none']

ValueError: Logistic Regression supports only solvers in ['liblinear', 'newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'sag', 'saga'], got multinomial.
```

Comment: why do you think there is a "multinomial" solver to choose? check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html): For multiclass problems, only ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’ and ‘lbfgs’ handle multinomial loss; ‘liblinear’ is limited to one-versus-rest schemes.

Comment: i read the reference of the solver in the  course of educative inc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `solver='multinomial'` with `multi_class='multinomial'`. There is no 'multinomial' solver.

In the comments you mention,

> i read the reference of the solver in the course of educative inc

Don't read reference/docs anywhere else, use scikit-learn's website,
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html

Please read the docs.

Comment: N1kshan: what @RainingComputers said. There are thousands of copycat blogs and courses, scraping, mutilating and distorting content in order to get Google hit, clicks and eyeballs. Disregard them and go straight to the source, https://scikit-learn.org/